# Problem with ASP.NET MVC Edtior Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I am trying to create an editor template for column in a Telerik MVC Grid.  After clicking edit this simple string column should show the same string value and next to it I would like to show a button or image with an onclick event.

I CAN'T DO THIS!

I have found some really simple examples.  Let's forget about the button or image for now and just display the same damn string, based on instructions found in this article:
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.Encode(ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue) %>
```

and:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue %>
```

or:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Model %>
```

None of these work.  In fact, when I step into this server side, ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue and Model don't have a value.  What's going on?  What is it in the grid that is preventing this?  More complex Editor Templates like comboboxes persist the data back to the editor template.

How can I simply display the same text in an editor template with some further options like buttons that I will later change the data?

Steve

Comment: I'm curious.  Why are you using an EditorTemplate to display data?  You should be using a DisplayTemplate.  Are you also naming the files correctly?  I haven't used WebForms engine in a long time, so I can't remember if it needs to be ascx or aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Steve, can you provide a sample of your controller code?  It sounds as though it's not setting the model data correctly.